# How do I skip one iteration of a for loop in the debugging mode in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, for-loop, debugging, iteration

I wanna skip one iteration of a for loop with a lot of `if` statements. When i click the `Step Over` it just jumps into the `if` statements.

> for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {}

Can I just skip from one iteration of the loop into the next iteration?

Comment: you can use continue statement in the loop

Comment: @MunsifAli No I just want to inspect how the elements are added to a certain list... I don't actually want to skip an iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint inside the loop and every time the debugger pauses at that breakpoint you can resume the debugger and it will pause again inside the loop for the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional breakpoint, with condition i>0
You can find more information here https://developer.android.com/studio/debug